# How to write a raster with RAT factors in R raster package

Tags: r, raster

I want `writeRaster` to write the RAT (raster attribute table) that I've built in R.

I'm running R 3.0.1, raster 2.1-49, and rgdal 0.8-10.

My input raster looks like this:

```
r <-raster("F:/test.img")

class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 3, 3, 9  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
extent      : 347325, 347415, 4301655, 4301745  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=18 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : F:\test.img 
names       : test 
values      : 1, 19  (min, max)
```

I then build my attribute table:

```
r <- ratify(r)
rat <- levels(r)[[1]]
rat$Pixel_Values <- c(1, 7, 8, 9, 19)
rat$Class_Names <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
levels(r) <- rat
```

Which results in a `raster` with attributes:

```
r

# class       : RasterLayer 
# dimensions  : 3, 3, 9  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
# extent      : 347325, 347415, 4301655, 4301745  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=18 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
# data source : F:\test.img 
# names       : test 
# values      : 1, 19  (min, max)
# attributes  :
#  ID Pixel_Values Class_Names
#   1            1           A
#   7            7           B
#   8            8           C
#   9            9           D
#  19           19           E
```

I then attempt to write my raster together with its RAT:

```
ratRaster <- "F:/testRat.img"
writeRaster(r, filename=ratRaster, datatype="INT1U", RAT=TRUE, progress="window", overwrite=TRUE)
```

But when I read it back into R, it becomes apparent that the attributes did not persist:

```
r2 <- raster(ratRaster)

r2
# class       : RasterLayer 
# dimensions  : 3, 3, 9  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
# extent      : 347325, 347415, 4301655, 4301745  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=utm +zone=18 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
# data source : F:\testRat.img 
# names       : testRat 
# values      : 1, 19  (min, max)
```

It would be quick and awesome to build RATs in R. How can I create and export the raster and keep the RAT?

Comment: `library(raster); set.seed(1); r <- raster(matrix(sample(c(1, 7:9, 19), 100, replace=TRUE), 10))` will provide a reproducible example raster.

Comment: Any reason why you did not accept my answer? It is not automatic when you give the bounty.

Comment: @cmbarbu - it's not my question... I put a bounty on an existing Q.

Answer (score 4):

Note that if you use raster's native *.grd* format (see [doc](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/vignettes/rasterfile.pdf), section 3.3) , the RAT table will be saved:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrows=5, ncols=5)
r[] <- rep(1:5, 5)
r <- ratify(r)
rat <- levels(r)[[1]]
rat$Pixel_Values <- 1:5
rat$Class_Names <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
levels(r) <- rat

r
writeRaster(r, filename="raster_rat.grd")
```

Now re-open:

```
r2 <- raster("raster_rat.grd")
r2
```

Answer (score 2):

You could always write the RAT as a csv file, then join that data later.

Write your raster as you specified:

```
writeRaster(r, filename=ratRaster, datatype="INT1U", RAT=TRUE, progress="window", overwrite=TRUE)
```

Write the attribute data/table/RAT as a .csv file:

```
write.csv(rat, file="C:\\merp\\rat.csv", row.names = F)
```

Then you can join this data in another program later. 
For example, if exporting from R to ArcMap, write the raster to disk, write the attribute data as csv file, then join your RAT to the raster using the [Add Join](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-join.htm) tool in ArcMap.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [definition of writeRaster](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29020797/1174052) writing the RAT is clearly not implemented, at least for the native and the GTif format. Actually, one of the first things done is to remove the RAT. Not too surprising given the comments in ratify() help:

> The functions documented here are
>        mainly available such that files with a RAT can be read and
>        processed; currently there is not too much further support.

From and to R you can always use

```
    save(r,file=ratRaster)
```

and then

```
    load(ratRaster)
```

It keeps everything.

Comment: shame about not being able to write a raster with a RAT!! would save a lot of time....